# windows service - installing 2 copies

Tags: .net, windows, service, windows-services

I have a windows service running on my server.

Now I want to install a modified version of it for testing, but without uninstalling the original one.

I've created a separate folder for the new service but when I try to install it I get an error:

"the specified service already exists"

Why is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services have to have a unique name. You should register your test service with a different name from the true service.

Comment: where should I change the name for it though? in the exe file?

Comment: Well, where in your code do you specify the service name? This is the name that appears in the service control manager.

Comment: Rename an existing service in the registry: http://serverfault.com/questions/200038/rename-windows-service

Comment: @themel That's a very dirty way to do it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: True. I'm assuming OP has no access to the service's source code and is actually asking a question that should be on ServerFault.

Comment: @themel "Now I want to install a modified version of it for testing" sounds like they wrote the service

Comment: @user I believe that you will have specified the name when you set [`ServiceBase.ServiceName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.servicename.aspx)

Comment: @David Heffernan thanks - I changed the Display Name and Service Name under the serviceInstaller properties and it worked